# git rebase re-hashes untouched commit

Tags: git, rebase

### Situation

These are the commit hashes in my branch. The PUSHED commits are part of the public master which was the base of my branch. The other commits are not yet pushed to public.

```
PUSHED_A - PUSHED_B - mywork_A - mywork_B - correction_A
```

Now I used `git rebase -i` to reorder and squash correction_A into mywork_A.
I understand why mywork_A and mywork_B have a new commit hash after rebasing.

But now even PUSHED_B has got a new hash. The hashes now look like this

```
PUSHED_A - PUSHED_B2 - mywork_A2 - mywork_B2
```

I am afraid this will make it hard to correctly merge my branch into the public master branch because PUSHED_B2 is not recognized as the alread existing PUSHED_B and will cause problems.

I corrected that (new branch, cherry picking...) but I don't understand the backgrounds.

#### Why did that happen?

I looked at the commit content of both PUSHED_B and PUSHED_B2. There is no difference.

Perhaps I took PUSHED_B into the list of commits when doing the rebase, chosing HEAD~x too large. But I did not modify this commit and didn't reorder something before it. So even if it was part of the commits in the list, shouldn't it be left as it was?

Can I trace back what happened and when this happened?

Comment: it is probably better to use 'merge' on the public branch. You will not have to worry about the public state of it then.

Comment: @Serge Yes, it may work, but you'll end up with duplicate commits such as PUSHED_B and PUSHED_B2 cluttering the public history.

Comment: you may end up with headache and in more extra commits trying to fix the remote site after the local rebase, as you are probably discovering.

Answer (score 2):

Note that *some* forms of `git rebase` attempt to notice that a particular existing commit can be reused, and will then re-use that existing commit (by "fast forwarding").  If you don't want that to happen, `git rebase` offers options to disable it.  *Other* forms of `git rebase` are less careful about this: in effect, those options are always on.  It seems likely you used the less-careful form of rebase.

The [BEHAVIORAL DIFFERENCES section of the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_behavioral_differences) alludes to the three "back end" internal implementations: *am* (which uses `git format-patch` and `git am` to accomplish the copying, rather than cherry-picking commits), *merge* (which uses cherry-pick), and *interactive* (which uses cherry-pick but first generates an instruction sheet that you can edit, and gets pretty fancy):

- The *am* back-end is the less-careful form.  It is also the default.
- The front end `git rebase` command switches to the *merge* back-end if you supply `-m`, `-s`, or `-X` options.
- The front end `git rebase` command switches to the *interactive* back-end if you use `-i`.

In Git a year or so ago, rebase was mainly written as shell scripts and it was easier to tell which rebase did what.  The new one is in C and much more opaque.  The `-p` option used to us the interactive back end, but not interactively, and maybe still does; the `-r` or `--rebase-merge` might also.  It's clear that neither uses the old *am* back end, and, from the description in the documentation, that `-k` cannot use the *am* back end either.

As [kan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817258/1256452), you can re-rebase to put the two have-to-be-different commits back atop the original sequence of commits.  Or, as you did, you can use `git cherry-pick` manually, which gives you full control over every step, at the price of requiring full control over every step. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you rebase, it changes 'committer' and date of rebased commits, hence there is a new hash.

Simplest way is to rebase again against upstream using correct commit range. In this case git will detect that PUSHED_B and PUSHED_B2 has the same content, and will skip the latter.

Comment: How would 'rebase again against upstream using correct commit range' look like in my case? I am still to unfamiliar with rebase.

Comment: If you have default branch set up, then `git fetch; git rebase` will do the magic usually. In this case `git rebase PUSHED_B` should do the same.

Comment: I'll try that. You say 'When you rebase, it changes ... hence there is a new hash' so that means in further rebases I have to provide the correct number of commits to include in the interactive list because ALL commits in it are touched, even if I leave them on 'pick' and don't change them in any way?

Comment: When you rebase, you should provide a new base, i.e. a commit on top of which all rebased commits are applied. So, you should just choose the base properly, not picking random stuff with HEAD~x

Comment: @Droidum When you `rebase -i`, then an initial sequence of commits keeps their hashes as long as you leave them completely untouched. You can savely use a too large value for `x` in `HEAD~x` provided that the history since then is linear. If you have merges since `HEAD~x`, your bets are off.

Comment: @j6t Yes, you are right. I am not sure how exactly he managed to create the `PUSHED_B2`, however I believe the additional rebase should remove it, no matter how it was created.

Comment: @j6t I'd like to know too, how did I accomplish that :-) Is there a tool or log or something that could help me to find out what happened?

Comment: Try `git reflog` it may give you a hint what kind of commands you have typed.

Comment: @Droidum Note that plain `git rebase` (without `-i`) does rewrite all commits; it does not check whether some commits can be left unchanged.